QField: Vice-versa auto-fill of two fields using value relation
I am setting up geopackage in QGIS (LTR 3.28.15) to be used in the field with QField (3.2 - Congo) for mapping birds.
My geopackage has the following layers:

Brutvoegel: Point geometry for saving my observations, among others having two fields a) "Art" to map the species and b) "Art_kurz" to insert the abbreviation of the species
sl_brutvoegel: A non-spatial table with information for each species (SL_Art - species, SL_Wissenschaftlicher_Name - scientific name, SL_Artenkürzel - abbreviation) working as a  look-up table to automatically fill field attributes

My goal: I want to set up the attribute forms in QGIS in a way that I can fill one of the two fields (either Art or Art_kurz) and based on that one field it automatically updates the other field. Example: I can type Amsel (with autocomplete functionality and suggestions from the look-up table field "SL_Art") as the species in the field "Art" and it automatically fills the field "Art_kurz" with an A. It should also work the other way round, so that I can type A as abbreviation (with autocomplete functionality and suggestions from the look-up table field "SL_Artenkürzel") in the field "Art_kurz" and based on that it will fill the field "Art" with my corresponding species Amsel
For now I am using a combination of value relation widget (to refer to my key list with the layer: sl_bruvoegel, key_column: SL_Art|SL_Artenkürzel, value_column: SL_Art|SL_Artenkürzel) and default values (to fill one field based on the other one).
My current approach (see details below) perfectly works in QGIS, but when I import my project to QField it does not automatically updates the fields and I have no clue why... (link to screen recording
How can I correctly set up my geopackage in a probably more easy way, so that it works stable in QField?
Here is my current approach in QGIS:
Note:
My intuitive idea to fill the field "Art"|"Art_kurz" based on its counter field by simply setting the default value as "Art_kurz"|"Art" and set the key column of the value relation widget to SL_Artenkürzel|SL_Art and the value_column to SL_Art|SL_Artenkürzel somehow did not work in this "double auto-fill" problem.
Attribute form settings for the field "Art" (species):

Expression for the default value:
CASE
WHEN "Art_kurz" is not NULL OR "Art_kurz" != '' 
THEN attribute(get_feature('sl_brutvoegel','SL_Artenkürzel',"Art_kurz"),'SL_Art')
END

Attribute form setting for the field "Art_kurz"

Expression for the default value:
CASE
/* Holt sich den Ausgangswert "SL_Artenkürzel" aus der Schlüsselliste sl_brutvoegel */
WHEN "Art" is not NULL OR "Art" is not ''
THEN attribute(get_feature('sl_brutvoegel','SL_Art',"Art"),'SL_Artenkürzel')
END


have you enabled "Fast edit mode" in Qfield? Does it change your behaviour?

"Fast edit mode" is deactivated and there is no change in behaviour when I switch it on

I had no success with CASE...WHEN. My way to go was then:
For the german Art field:
map_get(attributes(get_feature('sl_brutvoegel','SL_Artenkuerzel',attribute('Art_kurz'))),'SL_Art')

And vice versa for the Art_kurz field:
map_get(attributes(get_feature('sl_brutvoegel','SL_Art',attribute('Art'))),'SL_Artenkuerzel')

I hope I did not mix up your field, if so I hope you still get the idea!
The rest of your QGIS setup looks fine (on both fields the "Apply default value on update" must be checked..)

Thanks for the code snippet which looks way cleaner than mine.
It works fine when I start with the field of the abbreviated species name Art_kurz, then it perfectly fills the related field Art.
However, it still don't work vice versa. When I fill my field Art with e.g. 'Amsel', the value is not inserted.
Could it be that there is a conflict between the automated live default value and the manual text input?
Here is again a link to a screen recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/111raO-6FoqOSMGQoSrMpENTsIB55Rxlx/view?usp=sharing

I have the feeling that this issue is related to the device I am using or occurs randomly. The described observation happens on my samsung tablet (Android) as well as on my panasonic toughpad (Windows). When I tried your approach on my qfield desktop version (Windows), it perfectly worked...

can you share the project? you find my mailadress on my profile i think..maybe i can have a look!

Short update: Sn1ks and me both set up a completey new geopackage from scratch with exactly the same settings, and it perfectly worked, first...
But after a few testings the erroneous behavior came up again for my case - it was only possible to fill in the abbreviation field Art_kurz and the species field Art was automatically updated. Vice versa it did not work...
